# Inkscape - How to clip text from shape and get a resulting path?

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

I have been given a .svg file with text that I want to modify with Inkscape. The text has been 'clipped' out of a rectangle so the text is no longer modifiable (*I think*).

[ender2.svg](https://gistcdn.githack.com/spuder/111a0e36a55828827b0a4328b142dc19/raw/412b4c61b52bbbcc689b7082555c97aad9c13fa7/ender2.svg)

[image]

I can tell the source type is 'path' because if I view the 'nodes' of the rectangle it shows 109 path nodes

[image]

### Attempt 1

I've tried the following to create a *new* text block

- creating a rectangle
- Adding text
- Doing 'clip' -> inverse

This *appears* to have done what I wanted, however the resulting object is a path with only 4 nodes which isn't what I want

[ender2pro.svg](https://gistcdn.githack.com/spuder/111a0e36a55828827b0a4328b142dc19/raw/f6756c6a6ce21226462841c22286e3d5251ec33a/ender2pro.svg)

[image]

- **How can I convert this 4 node path into a more detailed 109 node path like the original file?

  Or is there a way I could edit the text on the original file?**

I'm brand new to inkscape so any assistance apprechiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use masks or clipping for this.

1. Draw a rectangle and type some text. Select both.
2. Do *Path > Difference*

Example

[image]

Comment: This is a much simpler approach than what I did. Confirmed that this does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a clip, do the following

1. Create a rectangle and text
2. Convert the text to a path (`path -> object to path`)
3. Select all the letters and ungroup them (`right click + ungroup`)
4. Select all the letters and join them (`path -> union`)
5. Select the rectangle and the path text then do a 'difference' or 'intersection' (`path -> difference`)

Here is a video showing the steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHC8sDX2Pmk

[image]